# Name generated when adding data in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I change or set the name generated when adding new data in the database using REST API? 
I have tried different solutions but none of them work.

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take an educated guess that you're using `POST` to add data to the Firebase Database. The [Firebase documentation says about `POST`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-post):

> To generate a unique, timestamp-based key for every child added to a Firebase database reference we can send a `POST` request.

I you want to control the key that gets used to store your data, you'll want to use a `PUT` request. The [documentation for `PUT`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-put) has a good explanation and example:

> Let's start by saving some user data to our Firebase database. We'll store each user by a unique username, and we'll also store their full name and date of birth. Since each user will have a unique username, it makes sense to use `PUT` here instead of `POST` since we already have the key and don't need to create one.

```
curl -X PUT -d '{
  "alanisawesome": {
    "name": "Alan Turing",
    "birthday": "June 23, 1912"
  }
}' 'https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/rest/saving-data/fireblog/users.json'
```

Note that the above is a liberal copy/pasting from the [Firebase documentation for the REST API of the Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-put).