# Assign increment ID number in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I want to post new data in Firebase Realtime Database with increment ID number like:

```
0 {
 'data' : 'value'
} 

1 {
 'data' : 'value'
}

2 {
 'data' : 'value'
}
```

When I use

```
final res = await http.post(
 apiUrl,
 body: json.encode({
  'data' : 'value',
 })
);
```

The object is created like this:

```
-N897xxxxx {
 'data' : 'value'
}

-N656xxxxx {
 'data' : 'value'
}
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-post), when you post successfully to Firebase Realtime, the return result will be "the child name of the new data specified in the POST request".

So POST is not what you want.

Instead, you can use PUT like this:

```
curl -X PUT -d '{
  "newpost": {
    "name": "1",
    "data" : "value",
  }
}' 'https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/rest/saving-data/fireblog/users.json'
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37956947/12806961) for more info.